# VBA Shell command with variables and spaces

Tags: excel, vba, shell, outlook

In a Microsoft Outlook macro, I'm trying to use a Shell() call to open an Excel spreadsheet (whose filepath is referenced by my `templatePath` variable). I keep getting syntax errors from the editor and "file not found" errors when executing it.

I started with the following line:

```
Shell ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"" ""C:\Users\My_Username\Desktop\My_Folder\Request Template.xlsx"""), vbNormalFocus
```

It opens the appropriate file just fine; I just don't know the proper syntax to use the `templatePath` variable instead of hard-coding the path to the spreadsheet. I've seen questions similar to this, but none seemed to fit my situation closely enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `application.TemplatesPath`  Will this be opened by you each time as the the username is in the path.   Is the file a template?  If so it may be template extension, not normal xls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Dim templatePath As String

templatePath = "C:\Users\My_Username\Desktop\My_Folder\RequestTemplate.xlsx"

Shell ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"" """ & templatePath & """"), vbNormalFocus
```

If your template resides in the `Application.TemplatesPath` and you just want to specify the file*name* then use:

```
templatePath = Application.TemplatesPath & "RequestTemplate.xlsx"
```

---

A more adjustable version:

```
Dim templatePath As String
Dim programPath As String
Dim templateName As String

templateName = "RequestTemplate.xlsx"
templatePath = Application.TemplatesPath
programPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"

Shell ("""" & programPath & """" & " " & """" & templatePath & templateName & """"), vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for the quick response-- all those quotation marks always confuse me.

Comment: When in doubt, a good way to 'proof' the quotes etc. is to send the text to the Immediate Window, instead of Shell to see what you're trying to send.